# Generating hash key and value from arrays ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am trying to make a hash in Ruby that has the key/value pair from 2 arrays indexes like in the example:

```
hash = {
    array1[0] => array2[0]
    array1[1] => array2[1]
    array1[2] => array2[2]
}
```

Is there any existing method that could help me achieve this kind of result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually remarkably easy.

Let's first [zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) two arrays together.

```
irb(main):003:0> [1, 2, 3].zip([4, 5, 6])
=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

And then we'll [convert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) that to a hash.

```
irb(main):004:0> [1, 2, 3].zip([4, 5, 6]).to_h
=> {1=>4, 2=>5, 3=>6}
```